# Significant amount of RAM missing

Tags: 14.04, ram, bitcoin

I have an Ubuntu server that is using bitcoind to download the blockchain and some other tasks. The blockchain is fully synced. I know that it can be a memory hog which is why I've tried to limit the amount of RAM it uses, but it seems that it is not successful.

The arguments I am using to reduce memory usage are:

```
-dbcache=20 
-maxsigcachesize=4 
-maxconnections=4 
-rpcthreads=1 
-par=2
```

cat /proc/meminfo Information:

```
MemTotal:        4194304 kB
MemFree:          282108 kB
Cached:          3634908 kB
Buffers:               0 kB
Active:           820684 kB
Inactive:        3077500 kB
Active(anon):     133488 kB
Inactive(anon):   132396 kB
Active(file):     687196 kB
Inactive(file):  2945104 kB
Unevictable:          64 kB
Mlocked:              64 kB
SwapTotal:             0 kB
SwapFree:              0 kB
Dirty:                 0 kB
Writeback:             0 kB
AnonPages:        265884 kB
Shmem:              2608 kB
Slab:              13920 kB
SReclaimable:       8096 kB
SUnreclaim:         5824 kB
```

Executing `ps aux  | awk '{print $6/1024 " MB\t\t" $11}'  | sort -n` gives me the following information:

```
0 MB        COMMAND
0 MB        [khelper/270]
0 MB        [kthreadd/270]
0.664062 MB     sh
0.753906 MB     sort
0.777344 MB     upstart-file-bridge
0.808594 MB     upstart-udev-bridge
0.828125 MB     /sbin/getty
0.832031 MB     /sbin/getty
0.972656 MB     awk
0.972656 MB     upstart-socket-bridge
1.10938 MB      ps
1.39844 MB      /lib/systemd/systemd-udevd
1.39844 MB      su
1.48047 MB      rsyslogd
1.70703 MB      tmux
2.04297 MB      -bash
2.06641 MB      -bash
2.54688 MB      init
3 MB        /usr/sbin/sshd
3.86328 MB      sshd:
29.4609 MB      /usr/lib/erlang/erts-5.10.4/bin/beam.smp
285.316 MB      ./bin/bitcoind
```

If bitcoind is only taking 285MB then why do I only have less than 300MB of RAM left out of 4GB? The bitcoind is ran inside a tmux session and after being killed I do not get any more RAM back.

Comment: Mandatory reference: https://www.linuxatemyram.com/

Answer (score 2):

Cached:          3634908 kB

This is your HDD read/write cache. Linux and most other OSs will use all available memory for drive cache. This cache size is not fixed. If your programs need  more memory then some it will be flushed to disk to make room for the running program.